# Run Applescript automatically when a PDF file is present within a folder

Tags: applescript

I have created an Applescript that requires to run automatically & repeat every time a pdf file is present within the folder on a server.

1. Look at the folder
2. File present?
3. Hold until file present
4. Activate script and complete
5. Look at folder - Repeat

Does anyone know where to start?

Comment: What is the server?

Comment: If your folder can be visible on your Desktop, try to assigned it to a Folder Action Script. This standard feature allows to runs a script each time a new file is added to the folder. I made that for some Windows server folders and it works..as long as the drive or folder is visible (launch).